# Using row filter and replace in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have searched the datagridview using `RowFilter`. Now I need to replace these text that the rows contain with some other text.

How do i do that?

```
private void button7_Click_3(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filterBy;
    filterBy = "Stringtext Like '%" + textBox6.Text + "%'";
    ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = filterBy;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What do you need to replace? The `Stringtext` column value? Or just the `textBox6.Text` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method below retrieves the data source of the `dataGridView1`as a `DataTable` and it clones it to a new `DataTable`. Then, it parses the `Rows` collection of the original `DataTable`, it replaces the looked up value (given by `textBox6.Text`) with the `_TEST_` value in the `Stringtext` column and it adds the modified rows to the cloned data table. Lastly, it assigns the grid's data source to the modified table.

```
private void button7_Click_3(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var original = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource);
    var clone = original.Clone();
    var ordinal = original.Columns["Stringtext"].Ordinal;
    for (int i = 0; i < original.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var values = original.Rows[i].ItemArray;
        values[ordinal] = values[ordinal].ToString()
            .Replace(textBox6.Text, "_TEST_");
        clone.Rows.Add(values);
    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = clone;
}
```